# How to specify content-type header in AWS API Gateway method_response using terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-api-gateway, terraform-provider-aws

I want to add a content-type to my `aws_api_gateway_method_response`. It should look like this:
[image]

How can I achieve this? With my current terraform code:

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_method_response" "response_200" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api.id
  resource_id = aws_api_gateway_resource.api_resource.id
  http_method = aws_api_gateway_method.mymethod.http_method
  status_code = "200"
}
```

it looks like this:

[image]

If i add this to my method_response:

```
response_parameters = {
    "Content-Type" = true
  }
```

I get an error that:

```
Error: BadRequestException: Invalid mapping expression specified: Validation Result: warnings : [], errors : [Invalid mapping expression specified: Content-Type]
```

What's the correct way to specify the content-type here?

Answer (score 1):

`response_models` param does it, from the [docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/api_gateway_method_response#attributes-reference)

> response_models - (Optional) A map of the API models used for the response's content type

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_method_response" "response_200_kinesis" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api_kinesis.id
  resource_id = aws_api_gateway_resource.api_resource_kinesis.id
  http_method = aws_api_gateway_method.post_json_files_kinesis.http_method
  status_code = "200"
  response_models = {
       "application/json" = "Empty"
  }
}
```

or if you want the header `Content-Type` to be provided in the response

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_method_response" "response_200_kinesis" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api_kinesis.id
  resource_id = aws_api_gateway_resource.api_resource_kinesis.id
  http_method = aws_api_gateway_method.post_json_files_kinesis.http_method
  status_code = "200"
  response_parameters = { "method.response.header.Content-Type" = true }
}
```

Comment: I tried the first one but I get an error that ```BadRequestException: Invalid model identifier specified: Empty```

Comment: which terraform version are you using @Jbd ?

Comment: @Jbd possibly works adding an `aws_api_gateway_integration_response` as this [example](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/10157#issuecomment-263560025) and a `aws_api_gateway_integration` as the [docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/api_gateway_integration_response) note.